# Autocomplete for typescript shows wrong path on VSCode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code

I've been facing some annoying trouble on typescript + VSCode when it comes to autocomplete:

Whenever I try to autoComplete, it never brings the correct path. If I am at `./src/components/foo` and I type `Bar` to get it from './src/components/bar/index.tsx', instead of autocomplete completes with `import {Bar} from '../bar'`, i always get `import {Bar} from 'src/components/bar'`

my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "rootDirs": ["src", "stories"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "my-lib": ["./node_modules/my-lib/dist/*"]
    }
  },

  "include": [
    "index.d.ts",
    "./src/**/*",
    "./stories/**/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `"baseUrl": ".",` from `tsconfig.json` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

**Update Vscode settings**

On VScode File>Preferences>Settings>User Settings

```
"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "relative"
```

Comment: Best answer. removing "baseUrl" from tsconfig.json could result in problems if you are using path resolvers.